# EF Core DB first - Do I need the index definitions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I am using EF Core (3.1 if that matters) with a DB first approach.
A while ago I generated the model using the Scaffold-DbContext command, and in the generated context file there are many index definitions, e.g.:
`entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.ItemType, e.ItemID });`

Since we had some index updates recently I was wondering - Do I actually need to update all the relevant index definitions in my model? Do I even need them at all? Do they have any influence on EF's performance or how the code runs, or can I just remove them and not worry about any updates made in the actual DB?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can  just ignore them. They are not used at runtime.

Comment: Are you sure about that @ErikEJ ?  Is it possible that EF will create different searches depending on if something is indexed or not (I'm think that a search that looks for COLA, COLB, would change the search to COLB,COLA if the index was specified that way).

Comment: Yes, I am sure about that

Comment: @dorBS do you mean you have created some indexes directly in your database tables and you have concerns with differences between your dbcontext and database?

Comment: @M.Mohabbati Exactly

Answer (score 0):

In the **Database-First** approach unlike **Code-First**, there is an existing database with its own configurations that may change in the future.

By this I mean, you always update your model based on the database objects and changes done in the database.

In your case, I suggest you use **Database Project** in visual studio for your database to make it under control by using **Source Control**. The following article might help you:

[Create Your First Visual Studio Database Project](https://medium.com/hitachisolutions-braintrust/create-your-first-visual-studio-database-project-e6c22e45145b)

To my mind, it is not important to keep the database changes in the same application project. Keep all database objects in another database project and only use the database model for your application model. You can build it and then deploy the database project on SQL Server.

---

Indexes do not directly affect **EF** functionality, but the database performance affects its output. "An index is an on-disk structure associated with a table or view that speeds retrieval of rows from the table or view."

[Clustered and nonclustered indexes described](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-ver15)